# Cannot upload image to laravel from react-native

Tags: laravel, react-native

I'm trying to let the user upload an image through **react-native**, but apparently, laravel is not being able to read any value from the request. This is what I'm trying to do with axios:

```
const data = new FormData()

            data.append('subject_id', this.props.navigation.getParam('id'))
            data.append('name', this.state.title)
            // I don't think the path is enough, it will probably just send the path as a string instead of the image. You need to load the actual file and append that
            data.append('image', {
                uri: this.state.image,
                type: 'image/jpeg',
                name: 'image'
            });
            data.append('progress', this.state.progress * 100)
            data.append('description', this.state.description)
            data.append('date', this.state.date)

            axios.post('https://example.com/api/auth/storeTask', data, {
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': access,
                    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
                },
            }).then(result => { })
                .catch(err => console.warn)
```

The image is not found when I try to access the resource.

Comment: Do you send CSRF token along with your data?

Comment: CSRF token in react-native? how to do that?

Comment: You don't need to send CSRF token from react-native. It should be disabled for external API routes, and protected in another manner (authentication tokens or similar)

Comment: That's exactly what i'm doing.

Comment: Whoops, my bad, sorry!

Comment: @Tony That's ok :) `react-native` is quite disconnected from Laravel, so it would be difficult to send a CSRF token with request from it. In most cases, your advice to send it with a `POST` request is 100% correct, but not in this situation.

Comment: What is the content of `this.state.image`?

Comment: @gbalduzzi it's the path to the image.

Comment: You will probably need to load the image and sent that, otherwise you are just sending a string, not a file

Answer (score 0):

You didn't send complete info like responses and logs, by the way,
Please check this instruction:

- make sure your CSRF in verifyCSRFtoken is allowed
- use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) to upload your file
- your code coulde be like this:

```
    import axios, { post } from 'axios';
    const url = '/uploadPic';
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("image", {
                name: this.state.photo.fileName,
                type: this.state.photo.type,
                uri: this.state.photo.uri,
              });
    const config = {
    headers: {
    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
    }
    const config = {
    headers: {
    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
    }
    return  post(url, formData,config)
```

for react native:
if you are in production and using react-native bare, you should add

```
<application
      ...
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
      ...
to your android file.
```

Comment: I'm using react-native, being this said. CSRF is not relevant here.

Comment: are you in production or development mode?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `FormData` object:

```js
const data = new FormData()

data.append('subject_id', this.props.navigation.getParam('id'))
data.append('name', this.state.title)
// I don't think the path is enough, it will probably just send the path as a string instead of the image. You need to load the actual file and append that
data.append('image', this.state.image)
data.append('progress', this.state.progress * 100)
data.append('description', this.state.description)
data.append('date', this.state.date)

axios.post('https://example.com/api/auth/storeTask', data, {
  headers: {
     'Authorization': access,
     "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
  },
}).then(result => {})
.catch(err => console.warn)
```

Comment: I already tried that this way, the problem is that data will be broken down in several objects and the backend won't be able to read the values.

Comment: Let me edit my question. Now the form works, but the image is not found.

Comment: I edited the question. Please feel free to check it out.